# Should I install the vanity, or the split faced stone first?

Tags: bathroom, tile, stone

We're going to do the entire vanity wall in [this tile](http://www.solistone.com/index.php?option=com_product&cate_id=67&pid=51&pro_id=125&level=2).

[image]

Here is the [vanity](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Foremost-Naples-36-in-W-Vanity-Cabinet-Only-in-Distressed-Grey-with-Left-Hand-Drawers-NADGA3621DL/205761213?cm_mmc=shopping-_-bingpa-_-29-_-205761213&ci_src=328768002&ci_sku=205761213&gclid=CNHNjNON4ckCFTP2Mgodj4kFAg&gclsrc=ds).

[image]

Originally we picked out a vanity that had open legs and probably could have been left freestanding in front of the wall.  But with this one I'm not so sure.

Do I install the vanity first, or the stone first (vanity over the stone)?

The advantage to doing the stone first is that my cuts become very minimal (just the wall edges), but then I'm thinking that the vanity will still need to be sealed to the wall.  Is that possible with the uneven surface of the tile?  With grout?

The other option is installing the vanity first, and then the stone around it.

Comment: Why do you think the vanity needs to be sealed to the wall?

Comment: @bib if you live in a house with kids, why it's a good idea to seal that spot becomes more obvious. :)

Comment: Kids are a factor and this is the main/high use bathroom for the house.

Comment: If that is the case, I would second @DA01 s comment that the backsplash is not very practical for that kind of use.

Comment: Yea, if this is a high-use bathroom, I think you need to think a bit more about usability. I know subway tile would be an entirely different look, but there is a reason why they are originally used in subways and are now so popular in kitchens...they are really easy to keep clean and sanitary. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've installed that tile. It's not to hard to cut--even by hand as you can just cut through the mesh backing. Even easier with a tile saw. So I'd suggest not tiling more than you have to and live with the cutting.

So I'd install the vanity first, then tile around it.

That said, note that that tile a) can't be grouted and b) is very uneven and c) porous and rough. I'd suggest *not* using that as a backsplash at all as cleaning it will be a nightmare...and no matter how dainty we may think we are in the bathroom, the backsplash *will* get splattered when washing hands, cleaning makeup, brushing teeth, etc. I fear that you will regret using that type of tile as a backsplash.

Comment: Thank you for the thought on the backsplash  I will make sure the sink has a high one or we will select a different tile for the backsplash.  It can't be grouted?  Sealing the edge must be done with silcone?

Comment: @b_levitt right, you can't grout that kind of tile. Where the tile meets another surface you can use a sanded caulk.